# consultar periodos de horários disponiveis na tabela SQL

Tags: sql, query

Estou desenvolvendo uma agenda de horários para um software que gerencia horários disponiveis para agendamento, parace até estranho eu postar isso aqui mais por incrivel que pareça não encontrei nada do genero aqui na web, bom o meu cenário é o seguinte:

tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE cad_compromisso
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  data_entrada date,
  nome_func character varying(50),
  servico character varying(100),
  horaini time without time zone,
  horafin time without time zone,
  nome_cli character varying(100)
)
```

onde na mesma eu guardo a data em que foi agendado o periodo que o cliente será atendido, que no caso são os campos "horaini" e "horafin", até ai tudo bem, agora o problema é que, toda vez que a atendente tenta criar um novo compromisso, é preciso verificar se já existe algum compromisso marcado dentro do periodo informado. Até agora não consegui deixar 100%,

o maximo que eu consegui foi isso:

```
select * from cad_compromisso
   where horafin <= '" & cmbhorafinal.Text & "'
   and horaini >= '" & cmbhorario.Text & "'
   or data_entrada = '" & calendario.Value & "'
   and nome_func = '" & cmbfuncionario.Text & "'
   and horafin > '" & cmbhorario.Text & "'
   and horaini < '" & cmbhorafinal.Text & "'
order by horaini "
```

se puderem mandar uma luz eu agradeceria...

Comment: Já tentou usar o between?

Answer (score 1):

Podes simplesmente tentar:

```
select *
from cad_compromisso
where data_entrada = '" & calendario.Value & "'
  and nome_func = '" & cmbfuncionario.Text & "'
  and (    '" & cmbhorario.Text & "'   between horaini and horafin 
        or '" & cmbhorafinal.Text & "' between horaini and horafin
        or ( horaini > '" & cmbhorario.Text & "' and horafin < '" & cmbhorafinal.Text & "')
  )
```

A lógica por trás da instrução é a seguinte: Considero que já existe um conflito com um outro compromisso quando **a data é a mesma**, **o funcionário é o mesmo** e existe uma **sobreposição de horário**.